# Modal VC not open (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, modalviewcontroller

How can I make the VC appear also

I tried this but ms loaded clean without buttons and TextView.

```
let modalViewController = ClipboardViewController()
modalViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
present(modalViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Example:**

[image: gif]

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        self.navigationController!.pushViewController(self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as UIViewController, animated: true)
    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
    // VC with animation
    } else if indexPath.row == 2 {
        self.navigationController!.pushViewController(self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Favorite") as UIViewController, animated: true)
    } else if indexPath.row == 3 {
        self.navigationController!.pushViewController(self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Settings") as UIViewController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: As you are expecting buttons, etc I assume you have set up the view controller in a storyboard or xib file.  If this is the case then you don't create it using this line `let modalViewController = ClipboardViewController()` or you will create one without any controls setup (as you have seen).  You need to instantiate it from the storyboard/xib or create a segue and perform that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    let modalViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ClipboardViewController ID") as? ClipboardViewController
    modalViewController?.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    self.present(modalViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```